# CodeIgniter OAuth 2 Server / Provider

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, oauth-2.0

Anyone know of a tutorial online that explains how to integrate alexbilbie CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server as there is no documentation provided.

https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server/

Or has anyone successfully integrated it and are able to provided a ZIP to download with their example.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to sort this? Having looked at the git hub link there are installation instructions in the 'How to use' section half way down.

Comment: @AlanLapington indeed there is. There's been updates to the OAuth project since I posted this and the new 'How to use' section in the README is very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [How to use](https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server/#how-to-use) section on the projects GitHub page has a great tutorial on how to get started.

*So this question does not show up as `Unanswered` and other users that stumble upon this page can find the link easier.*